# firebase firestore function is not defined in pure javsacript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have worked on react js with firebase and at there everything was working fine 
right now i am trying to connect the firebase and work with pure javascript no library and extensions etc so now i am having issue is that when i use

```
firebase.firestore();
```

then i m seeing an error that firestore is undefined 
this is the whole code

```
var firebaseConfig = {credentials}
const my_app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log(my_app)
my_app.firestore();
```

the credentials of firebase is ok as the same credentials i have used it before with react js
and in login.html i am using this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main_wrapper">
        <div class="login_form">
            <div class="email_field_area">
                <label for="email">Enter email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="login_email_field">
            </div>
            <div class="password_field_area">
                <label for="password">Enter password</label>
                <input type="text" name="password" class="login_password_field">
            </div>
            <div class="login_button">
                <button>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

added the cdn gstatic link of script . what should i do to make it run ?

and also console error is this 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you didn't include the script for Firestore, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment):

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Comment: awesome brother thanks for the quick help , i have searched alot but i didnt get this very simple help :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything to make the script run, it runs automatically once loaded.

As described in https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn, it is recommended that the scripts are placed at the bottom of your `<body>` rather than the head.

To use Firestore, you need to add the following library after the core Firebase SDK:

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```